# Ubuntu 14 not a valid iso

Tags: usb, iso

I have downloaded ubuntu-14.04.3-server-amd64.iso from the Ubuntu onto a Windows 7 pc.  I am using Windows 7 USB/DVD Tool to burn the it to an USB so I can boot my server from the USB and install.  I get an error saying the file is not a valid ISO.  What am I doing wrong (aside from using Windows)?  How can I fix this?  I do have Linux Mint running in VMWare.  New to Linux and want to learn.

Comment: Try using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) to burn it. If that doesn't work, redownload the ISO.

Comment: Thank you, Rufus worked great.  Installing my server now and am excited.

Comment: Yeah? Great! I'm fairly certain that the thing you were using is only for Windows images. Shall I add this as an answer?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: @Steve: If the answer below did help, just click the little grey **☑** under the number now, turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the number, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the Windows 7 DVD/USB Tool only works for Windows ISOs. I recommend using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) to burn your server image. Rufus works with most OSes and is extremely easy to use.